# NSUserDefaults swift. Сохранить и загрузить данные

Tags: ios, swift, apple, settings, nsuserdefaults

Есть View Controller настроек приложения. Где должно хранится имя , пол и т.д. В другом классе я использую action button что бы сохранить информацию в userDefaults ,но в классе настроек у меня нет 'экшенов '. И повторить обычную процедуру сохранения и доставание информации не получаеться. Все что мне нужно это хранить текст в Label и одно UIImage.
 Пока что имеется следущий код класса настроек пользователя

```
   //Передаю значения в лейбл на viewSettings


func textSetting()
{


    dateUserSettings.text = Singleton.shared.dateUser
    timeUserSettings.text = Singleton.shared.timeUser
    genderUserSettings.text = Singleton.shared.genderUser
    statusUserSettings.text = Singleton.shared.statusUser
    nameUserSettings.text = Singleton.shared.nameUser
    zodizImageOutlet.image = Singleton.shared.zodiacImage
    nameUserTitle.text = Singleton.shared.nameUser
    zodiacLabelOutlet.text = Singleton.shared.zodiacUser

        saveSettings()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad start ")

    textSetting()
     getSettings()
    switchPushOutlet.onTintColor = .blue
    switchPushOutlet.tintColor = .red
    setupNavBar()

}

//хранение информации пользователя
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
enum Key {
static let dateUser = "settingsDateUser"
static let timeUser = "settingsTimeUser"
static let genderUser = "settingsGenderUser"
static let statusUser = "settingsStatusUser"
static let nameUser = "settingsNameUser"
}

func saveSettings()
{


    defaults.set(dateUserSettings.text, forKey: Key.dateUser)
    defaults.set( timeUserSettings.text , forKey: Key.timeUser)
    defaults.set(genderUserSettings.text, forKey: Key.genderUser)
    defaults.set( statusUserSettings.text, forKey: Key.statusUser)
    defaults.set(nameUserSettings.text, forKey: Key.nameUser)

}

func getSettings() {
    dateUserSettings.text =  defaults.string(forKey: Key.dateUser)
    timeUserSettings.text =  defaults.string(forKey: Key.timeUser)
    genderUserSettings.text =  defaults.string(forKey: Key.genderUser)
    statusUserSettings.text =  defaults.string(forKey: Key.statusUser)
    nameUserSettings.text =  defaults.string(forKey: Key.nameUser)
    print("GetName Finish Settings")
}
```

Comment: Особо пока не вникая, для каждого значения должен быть свой ключ (а не один "settings" для всех). Сейчас у вас есть одна ячейка в UserDefaults  и вы туда, одно за другим, всё сохраняете (удаляя предыдущее),

Comment: Я исправил код  и поменял ключи. Но проблема в том что оно не хочет  сохранять данные статически. Если я например сделаю экшн кнопки "Cохранить"   и засуну туда метод saveSettings() , то все сохраняет . Но мне нужно сохранять без всяких кнопок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Defaults под собой представляет info.plist,
где данные хранятся в виде КЛЮЧ-ЗНАЧЕНИЕ.

> Одному ключу соответствует лишь одно значение

В представленном Вами коде вы каждый раз перезаписываете значение по вашему единственному ключу.

Вам *необходимо использовать набор ключей* для решения вашей задачи.

Например:

Вы можете создать следующий Enum

```
enum SettingsKeys {
    static let dateUser = "settingsDateUser"
    static let timeUser = "settingsTimeUser"
    static let genderUser = "settingsGenderUser"
    static let statusUser = "settingsStatusUser"
    static let nameUser = "settingsNameUser"
}
```

и использовать его так:

```
 defaults.set(dateUserSettings.text, forKey: SettingsKeys.dateUser)
 defaults.set(timeUserSettings.text, forKey: SettingsKeys.timeUser)
 defaults.set(genderUserSettings.text, forKey: SettingsKeys.genderUser)
 defaults.set(statusUserSettings.text, forKey: SettingsKeys.statusUser)
 defaults.set(nameUserSettings.text, forKey: SettingsKeys.nameUser)
```

Comment: Я попытался сделать как вы писали , но ничего не изменилось . Я исправил код  в вопросе на новый.

Comment: а у вас точно в синглтоне есть данные и они назначаются для Label?
Label у вас случайно не nil?

Comment: В синглтоне у мене переменные записаны так (var nameUser:String?)
Но когда происходит первый запуск преложения , пользователь заполняет все поля и переменные стают заполнены. Когда все заполнено и я перехожу на SettingsView  сразу не закрывая приложение , все поля заполнены, но если я выхожу все пропадает

Comment: Необходим более полный код, желательно на github

Comment: https://github.com/GlebiosDev/OracleS
Я закинул  пару файлов  с кодом

Comment: Каждый раз, когда ты заходишь в функцию saveSettings, в лэйбл есть текст?

Comment: Я исправил проблему , и сделал немного по другому . В первых View, где  пользователь вводит имена и тд , я сразу сохранял под  один ключ например  имя пользователя для всего приложения в дальнейшем  , и сохранял туда сразу  переменную из  синглтона и то что переменная хранила. И теперь с этого ключа я только  достаю уже в настройках имя, без сохранения.

Answer (score 0):

Экшен можно сделать без кнопки - на событие "окончание редактирования текста" для текстового поля:

**textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting

Для удобства можно вынести всю логику по работе с UserDefaults в отдельный файл - например, написать Extension для UD.